# Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance - UI Button - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, instance, extension-methods

I am programmatically creating a button and adding an action in the extension of my VC. Also, is there a better way to "delete" the views rather than hide them

```
func() setUpViews { 

    //views
    let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: Int((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - CGFloat(width)) / 2, 
    y: (Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)), width: width, height: height))
    shadowView.backgroundColor = .none
    let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    let blackView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: Int(self.navBar.bounds.height), width: 
    Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width), height: Int(self.rewardsTableView.bounds.height)))
    shadowView.setUpViewShadowForCell()
    blackView.backgroundColor = .black
    blackView.alpha = 0
    mainView.backgroundColor = color
    mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    mainView.clipsToBounds = true
    mainView.alpha = 1
    


    //close Button
    let closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat((Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - width) / 
    2), y: CGFloat((Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height) - height) / 2) + mainView.bounds.height, width: 
    mainView.bounds.width, height: 50))
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    closeButton.tintColor = .white
    closeButton.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("closeAction")), for: .touchDown)
```

Here is the function I am trying to run. Essentially, I want to delete the views out of display. Currently, I am hiding them and I am getting the error "unrecognized selector".

```
    //function to revert back to original, currently hiding
    func closeAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        blackView.isHidden = true
        mainView.isHidden = true
    }

    //adding the views
    self.view.addSubview(shadowView)
    self.view.addSubview(blackView)
    self.view.addSubview(closeButton)
    shadowView.addSubview(mainView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(shadowView)
   
}
```

Tried this:

```
     @objc func closeAction(sender: UIButton, UIView: UIView, UIView2: 
     UIView, 
     Button1: UIButton) {
     UIView.removeFromSuperview()
     UIView2.removeFromSuperview()
     Button1.removeFromSuperview()
     }
```

And In the actual Function:

```
    closeAction(sender: closeButton, UIView: shadowView, UIView2: 
    mainView, Button1: closeButton)
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeAction), for: 
    .touchDown)
```

Comment: What’s the full error message you get?

Comment: ...close Action] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffd57c208b0

Comment: Also realizing I need to delete the "close button"

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the proper syntax

```
#selector(closeAction)
```

Second of all you have to mark the action as `@objc` and it's recommended to use the real type of the sender rather than unspecified `AnyObject`

```
@objc func closeAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

To delete the button remove it from its `superView`

Comment: ok i get this:  (at symbol)objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes

Comment: The action method must be declared on the top level of the class, not inside another method

Comment: thanks vadian. once I move it outside of the class; how do i call the views created in the function since the extension cannot hold variables/constants?

Comment: Not outside of the class, on the top level of the class or extension, and please use exactly the suggested syntax in my answer. It's not possible to add more parameters.